# Custom table view cell in Swift, without Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm new to learning iOS development and the Swift language, and have been trying to figure out how to create a custom `UITableViewCell` without the use of Storyboards/Interface Builder. I'd like to be able to accomplish everything in Swift code. So far, I've only really been able to find ones that make use of the Interface Builder.

What I would like to be able to do is create a re-usable cell that can be instantiated in any table view. From what I understand I should be able to create a custom cell with sub-views, whos data can be set by the table view's incoming data. Right?

Right now I have a `UINavigationController` with an embedded, sub-classed `UITableViewController`. Following some other tutorials I've also learned how to create a Struct and prepare test data for the table view cell. But that's about as far as I've been able to get.

```
// My Table View Controller
class InventoryListViewController: MainTableViewController {

    let viewTitle = "Inventory"
    var inventoryItems = [InventoryItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = viewTitle.uppercaseString

        self.inventoryItems = [
            InventoryItem(name: "White Bread", expiry: "2014-09-12"),
            InventoryItem(name: "Mushrooms", expiry: "2014-09-15"),
            InventoryItem(name: "Watermelon", expiry: nil),
            InventoryItem(name: "Leftover Thai", expiry: "2014-09-15"),
            InventoryItem(name: "Cheddar Cheese", expiry: "2014-09-12"),
            InventoryItem(name: "Chicken Breasts", expiry: "2014-09-10"),
            InventoryItem(name: "Paprika", expiry: nil),
            InventoryItem(name: "Sour Cream", expiry: nil)
        ]

        // Right now this will fail without tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.inventoryItems.count
    }

}

// Sub-classed UITableViewController
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

}

// Data struct for cells
struct InventoryItem {
    let name: String
    let expiry: String?
}
```

I understand Swift is still very new and that's probably why I can't find too many resources for this topic, so if anyone has any pointers I would be very appreciative to the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use below code for custom cells without storyboard.Just register your `class` and use it  with `tableViewController`

```
//Cell.Swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

class Cell : UITableViewCell{

    //Do whatever you want as exta customization
}
```

Your controller viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // register your class with cell identifier
    self.tableView.registerClass(Cell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}


//cellForRowAtIndexPath

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:Cell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? Cell
        if cell == nil {

            cell = Cell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        //configure your cell custom code
         cell.textLabel?.text = @"Your Label Text"
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. This looks very promising, though when I try it out it errors at `self.configureCell` with `'MainTableViewController' does not have a member named 'configureCell'`. What would I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I have just added `confgureCell` for show to do custom code.You can remove it and there is no need for it.You can write your own code whatever you want to do like setting label.I am editing my code like to set label `cell.textLabel?.text = @"Your Label Text"`

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you! This seems to work! Though, if you don't mind explaining further - how do I add a new view (like a label) to the custom cell _within_ the `Cell` class? I tried doing [this](http://tny.cz/b83cf1bf) but it didn't work!

Comment: @JodyHeavener do not use `awakeFromNib` it is called only when you use storyBoard.Make custom method like `setUpCell` in Cell.swift and call it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like `cell.setUpCell()`

Comment: sorry for being annoying, you've been a tonne of help! I just can't seem to get it working - I'm probably following your advice wrong. Here's what I have done to try and add a view to the cell... http://tny.cz/a57fdcb0

Comment: this was helpful when i followed this (tutorial)[http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/] and they introduced xib files and i had to use a viewController created in a story board. I hadnt't created the UITableView in the storyboard yet i had a UITableViewCell. Thanks. Most tutorials assume you will have the TableView b default but i was working with parse, and i think their table is not yet accessible via the storyboard..